# How to install LLVM for Mac?

Tags: llvm, macos-sierra

How do I install LLVM on macOS Sierra? I've tried `brew install llvm` but when trying to use an llvm command like lli I get a command not found error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

homebrew does not link `llvm` to `/usr/local/bin` because it may conflict with the system one, causing all kinds of nasty bugs. Instead, you should use the full path to invoke them, such as `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/lli`.

In fact there's a Caveat that's now listed which spells this out...

> **==> Caveats**
>   ==> llvm
>
> To use the bundled libc++ please add the following `LDFLAGS`:
>     `LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"`
>
> llvm is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into `/usr/local`,
>   because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
>   parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.
>
> If you need to have llvm first in your PATH run:
>     `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
>
> For compilers to find llvm you may need to set:
>     `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"`
>     `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"`

Comment: Caveat: don't use macoc :))

Answer (score 6):

You can also add `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/` to your $PATH environment variable:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

This way you can call other `llvm` commands such as `llvm-config`. A list of llvm can be found [here](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/).

Comment: `brew link llvm` will possibly add llvm to the PATH also.

Answer (score 4):

Remember to `source .bash_profile`! I wasted a lot of time due to the silly problem.

Comment: Also restart Clion if you use this IDE

Comment: It is best to restart any IDE or terminal (although I don't know why).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to solve the issue on my High Siera MacOs after installing Xcode manually.

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib" >> ~/.bash_profile
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then I followed the instruction according to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69906054/4086606). I modified the OPs answer a bit by following @adam say to add this line *command* sure you add `cmake . -DLLVM_CREATE_XCODE_TOOLCHAIN=On.` before `cmake --build .`

My Build continued.

Answer (score 0):

If using `zsh` instead of `bash`:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

and then

```
source .zshrc
```

(obviously after brew installing)