# Installing node on macos 10.13.6 using brew, stuck on cmake --build

Tags: node.js, macos, cmake, llvm

1. MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6
2. brew install node

```sh
==> Installing node dependency: llvm
==> cmake -G Unix Makefiles .. -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang;clang-tools-extra;lld;lldb;mlir;polly -DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES=compiler-rt;libcxx;libcxxabi;libunwind;openmp -DLLVM_POLLY_
==> cmake --build .


[ 78%] Linking CXX static library ../../../lib/liblldELF.a
cd /tmp/llvm-20211220-23363-1hcbj8n/llvm-project-13.0.0.src/llvm/build/tools/lld/ELF && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.22.1/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /tmp/llvm-20211220-23363-1hcbj8n/llvm-project-13.0.0.src/llvm/build/tools/lld/ELF && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.22.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool" -static -no_warning_for_no_symbols -o ../../../lib/liblldELF.a CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/AArch64ErrataFix.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Arch/AArch64.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Arch/AMDGPU.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Arch/ARM.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Arch/AVR.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Arch/Hexagon.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Arch/Mips.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Arch/MipsArchTree.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Arch/MSP430.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Arch/PPC.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Arch/PPC64.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Arch/RISCV.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Arch/SPARCV9.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Arch/X86.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Arch/X86_64.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/ARMErrataFix.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/CallGraphSort.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/DWARF.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Driver.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/DriverUtils.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/EhFrame.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/ICF.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/InputFiles.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/InputSection.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/LTO.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/LinkerScript.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/MapFile.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/MarkLive.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/OutputSections.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Relocations.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/ScriptLexer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/ScriptParser.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/SymbolTable.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Symbols.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/SyntheticSections.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Target.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Thunks.cpp.o CMakeFiles/lldELF.dir/Writer.cpp.o

[ 78%] Built target lldELF
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Why do I keep getting stuck here?

How long does this Installing node dependency: llvm take!

Comment: how long are you waiting?

Comment: same issue here.  stuck at `cmake --build .` while installing llvm, about 90 minutes. Had previously hung at other points in the install. I'm on MacOS Mojave, attempting to resolve this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70454436/npm-err-code-1-after-syntaxerror-when-running-npm-ci-npm-run-build

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69906053/how-to-install-llvm13-with-homerew-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-6-got-built-tar

Comment: Took me 34 minutes to install in Big Sur.