# `npm ERR! code 1` after SyntaxError when running `npm ci && npm run build`

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line, macos-mojave, npx

I am trying to build and run a project on an npx dev-server. My `package.json` file has `"type":"module"` inside the first {} as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62554884/6069097). When I run `npm ci && npm run build` in terminal (MacOS Mojave), I get the following error message:

```
[!] SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
/Users/User/folder/project/node_modules/rollup-plugin-lit-css/rollup-plugin-lit-css.js:1
import { createFilter } from "rollup-pluginutils";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:720:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/Users/User/folder/project/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/loadConfigFile.js:622:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/User/folder/project/rollup.config.js:7:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/Users/User/folder/project/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/loadConfigFile.js:619:20)

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/User/folder/project/
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c rollup -c && workbox generateSW
```

The debug logs give the following additonal error info:

```
22 verbose stack Error: command failed
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:63:27)
```

When I try to run an npx server using `npx @web/dev-server --root-dir static --app-index static/index.html`, I get this error:
`npm ERR! could not determine executable to run`

I've tried updating npm through a number of methods:

`npm rm -rf node_modules`

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

but am still getting the same errors.

Any suggestions on where to start would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Had to update MacOS to Big Sur, then completely uninstall and reinstall node and npm.