# Error installing llvm on MacOs High Siera using Brew

Tags: homebrew, llvm, macos-sierra, vips

I have tried to follow the instruction [here](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/02/24/installing-llvm-clang-on-osx/) but my installation hang on

```
2d9d78074b6123ce1571c4ff59e3c4f2c9142e0f--poppler-data-0.4.11.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-21.12.0.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/macbookpro/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/c16ebee699cf7e29800e8a8be3cf4a5e5298e493d1b572f74ee4efdd0713fe7a--poppler-21.12.0.tar.xz
==> Installing vips dependency: llvm
==> cmake -G Unix Makefiles .. -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang;clang-tools-extra;lld;lldb;mlir;poll
==> cmake --build .
```

Actually I am trying to install `vips`

```
brew install vips
```

Comment: This looks like something you want to report in their bugtracker

Answer (score 1):

I got around this using the answer from here [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69906054/4086606). I modified the answer a bit by make sure I did  this `cmake . -DLLVM_CREATE_XCODE_TOOLCHAIN=On`. do? I tried it before this `cmake --build . --target install-xcode-toolchain`.

and continue with
`brew install vips`. Everything works fine on my MacOs High Siera in which I install Xcode manually since **Vips** needs either **ninja**, **Xcode** or **Visual Studio** to build.