# Is it possible to install Node.js on macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6? This is the latest version my mid 2014 Macbook Pro can support

Tags: node.js, homebrew, macos-high-sierra, dyld

My mid 2014 Macbook Pro can't be updated past High Sierra 10.13.6. I am trying to install ANY version of node.js. Is there any way to get Node.js running on my device? My end goal is to use Angular

---

I used brew to install node in Terminal:

```bash
brew install node
```

I was given this warning amongst other stuff:

> Warning: You are using macOS 10.13.
> We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.

After installation, I tried the following:

```bash
node
```

I got this in response:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
> Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
> Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
> Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
> Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>
> Abort trap: 6

Comment: You could run linux in a virtual machine.  The best VM software costs money but VirtualBox is free.

Comment: @DaveS thank you very much for taking the time to read and comment Dave, I will look into this.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into a similar problem and here's how I fixed it:

1. Download and install **nvm** from this GitHub link: [github.com/nvm-sh/nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)
2. Run the following commands:

`export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"`

`[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"`

`[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"`

3. Reload the bash_profile using `source ~/.bash_profile`
4. Check if nvm is installed using `nvm --version`. You should get something like **0.39.2** in the output
5. Once nvm is installed, run `nvm install 17.9.1` to install Node 17.9.1
6. Check node and npm versions to make sure they have been installed correctly using `node -v` and `npm -v`. You should get outputs like **v17.9.1** and **8.11.0** respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment Aniket, I hope to try this when I feel up for it

Comment: > `source ~/.bash_profile`

< `bash: /Users/[[redacted]]/.bash_profile: No such file or directory`

Comment: I skipped the step and everything worked.

Comment: It can be also called .bash-profile (with hyphen).

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem...

I believe the last nodejs version suported by high sierra is v17.9.1

https://nodejs.org/download/release/v17.9.1/

Comment: Thanks so much for reading and commenting Gabriel, I appreciate it! I will see if I can figure out how to install it

Comment: Just download the .dmg file and install as a normal package.

Comment: Superb. I just installed node.js version 17.9.1 on mac OS Sierra v10.12.6 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at English, please read with consideration
You can also install node v21.7.0

```
brew install llvm@12
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/cc # on line 80
"#{ENV["HOMEBREW_PREFIX"]}/opt/llvm/bin/#{Regexp.last_match(1)}"
```

rewrite this as below

```
"#{ENV["HOMEBREW_PREFIX"]}/opt/llvm@12/bin/#{Regexp.last_match(1)}"
```

llvm@15 is required, there are several ways

[How to install llvm@13 with Homerew on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6? Got "Built target lldELF" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69906053/how-to-install-llvm13-with-homerew-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-6-got-built-tar)

or

```
brew install --cc=llvm_clang llvm@15
```

download, Extraction, copying, takes time, before make

```
/tmp/llvmA15...../llvm-project-15.0.7.src/lldb/source/Host/macosx/objcxx/HostInfoMacOSX.mm # on line 236

if (cputype == CPU_TYPE_ARM64 && cpusubtype == CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM64E) {

rewrite this as below

if (cputype == CPU_TYPE_ARM64) {
```

After installing llvm@15

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/cc # on line 80

"#{ENV["HOMEBREW_PREFIX"]}/opt/llvm@12/bin/#{Regexp.last_match(1)}"
```

rewrite this as below

```
"#{ENV["HOMEBREW_PREFIX"]}/opt/llvm@15/bin/#{Regexp.last_match(1)}"
```

Set environment variables in .zshrc or .bashrc

```
export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1
brew edit node
```

rewrite line 36 as a comment

```
# on_macos do  
#   depends_on "llvm" => [:build, :test] if DevelopmentTools.clang_build_version <= 1100  
# end
```

Disable System Integrity Protection (SIP)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection

```
sudo cp /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/os/signpost.h /usr/include/os/
sudo vim /usr/include/os/signpost.h # on line 280

#define os_signpost_event_emit(log, event_id, name, ...) \\  
   os_signpost_emit_with_type(log, OS_SIGNPOST_EVENT, \\  
    event_id, name, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

rewrite this as below

```
#define os_signpost_event_emit(log, event_id, name, ...)  
   // os_signpost_emit_with_type(log, OS_SIGNPOST_EVENT, \\  
    event_id, name, ##__VA_ARGS__)

brew install --cc=llvm_clang node
```

Enable SIP if you don't want to touch the system

Summarized, read the link for more details

https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4751

Answer (score 0):

For mac 10.13.X the solution for me was to alter the nvm install version on my mac to:

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash`

then install the last version that works on my os.

```
`nvm install 16.20.2`
```

then `nvm -v` & `node -v`. both commands now return values rather than the error the original poster and I experienced.   I selected the versions simply by correlating release dates from the nvm github repo and the Nodejs.org so these are untested in terms of compatibility on my mac but this has gotten me to start running frameworks

Answer (score -1):

I installed nodejs19 via macports on High Sierra

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer

Comment: NodeJS19 does not work with High Sierra. The latest version to use with High Sierra is 17.9.1 as Gabriel stated and that is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

In case you need new verson of nodejs. I believe, it's possible to install linux/windows on older macbooks to use nodejs 18+.